# Scrapy: Difference between simple spider and the one with ItemLoader

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, css-selectors

I've been working on scrapy for 3 months. for extracting selectors I use simple response.css or response.xpath..

I'm asked to switch to ItemLoaders and use add_xpath add_css etc.

I know how ItemLoaders work and ho convinient they are but can anyone compare these 2 w.r.t efficiency? which way is efficient and why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Item Loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) are a convenient abstraction that allows you to reuse extraction code among multiple spiders inside a given Scrapy project.

Let's say you have a Scrapy project to scrape data from several e-commerces. You'll have multiple spiders (one for each website, most likely), but they will all share the same schema for the data you're extracting. Let's say your `ProductItem` class looks like this:

```
class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    ...
```

Now, let's say that in some of the websites the `price` field contains commas as separators in the price, such as `1,459.99`. If you want to get rid of that comma to standardize the output for that field, you'd have to mix formatting logic inside your spider, and that can easily lead to a mess.

If you create an `ItemLoader` for your `ProductItem` class, you can define processors for each field, so that you don't have to add formatting code into your spiders. Something like this:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

class ProductItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = ProductItem
    # an input processor for your price field
    price_in = MapCompose(lambda x: x.replace(',', ''))
```

Now, whenever you use this in your spiders:

```
loader = ProductItemLoader(response=response)
loader.add_css('price', '#price::text')
...
yield loader.load_item()
```

The input processor for the `price` field is gonna be called to format the field for you.

I recommend you to read the [documentation on item loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) to have a better understanding on the example I provided above.

**TL;DR:** item loaders are a convenience that Scrapy offers to help you better organize your spiders, avoiding mixing formatting rules (for example) in your spider code.

Answer (score 0):

Item loaders do exactly the same thing underneath that you do when you don't use them. So for every `loader.add_css/add_xpath` call there will be `responce.css/xpath` executed. It won't be any faster and the little amount of additional work they do won't really make things any slower (especially in comparison to xml parsing and network/io load).

Comment: So my spider starts very slow when I use item loader, is it normal or do I need to optimize the code?? it took like 1 min which is irritating sometimes. specially in testing as I've to run it again and again...

Comment: that is very strange, normally there is no way an item loader can slow down the startup in any significant way, perhaps include code of your spider with and without item loaders